# Bing Conversion Code Onsubmit Event

Tags: php, javascript, bing, onsubmit

Hello I would like to implement my Bing conversion code via a standard event.

What would be the best way to do this.  I have researched and bing only gives conversion code to be placed on the "thank you"/results page that is being tracked.  I want to track a submission with no thankyou page.

Do i need to use the bind function or ajax with javascript to act as a virtual visitor to a conversion page?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.mstag) mstag = {loadTag : function(){},time : (new Date()).getTime()};</script> <script id="mstag_tops" type="text/javascript" src="//flex.atdmt.com/mstag/site/adf15577-4e29-4422-a6a6-371877293cb3/mstag.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> mstag.loadTag("analytics", {dedup:"1",domainId:"1794519",type:"1",revenue:"15",actionid:"77282"})</script> <noscript> <iframe src="//flex.atdmt.com/mstag/tag/adf15577-4e29-4422-a6a6-371877293cb3/analytics.html?dedup=1&domainId=1794519&type=1&revenue=15&actionid=77282" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden;display:none"> </iframe> </noscript>
```

this is the conversion code i want activated with an onsubmit event.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function bang() {

    var s1 = document.createElement("script");
    s1.type = "text/javascript"
    s1.text = "if(!window.mstag) mstag = {loadTag : function(){},time : (new Date()).getTime()};";
    document.body.appendChild(s1);

    var s2 = document.createElement("script");
    s2.type = "text/javascript"
    s2.src = "//flex.atdmt.com/mstag/site/sdfsfsdf-5555-49bb-9a12-a8d0d341d336/mstag.js";
    document.body.appendChild(s2);

    var s3 = document.createElement("script");
    s3.type = "text/javascript"
    s3.text = 'mstag.loadTag("analytics", {dedup:"1",domainId:"1130798",type:"1",actionid:"21354"})';
    document.body.appendChild(s3);

    var ns = document.createElement("noscript");
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iiframe.src = "//flex.atdmt.com/mstag/tag/sdfsfsdf-5555-49bb-9a12-a8d0d341d336/analytics.html?dedup=1&domainId=1130798&type=1&actionid=21354";
    iframe.frameborder = "0";
    iframe.scrolling = "no";
    iframe.width = "1";
    iframe.height = "1";
    iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    ns.appendChild(iframe);
    document.body.appendChild(ns);

    return true;
}
```

Then

```
 onsubmit="return bang();"
```

Comment: It does not seem to work; it does get the needed JS files, but does not perform the final call to flex.atdmt.com/mstag/tag/...

Comment: `document.createElement("noscript")` :) If you look at the contents of  mstag.js (and put it through something like http://jsbeautifier.org/) you will see it looks for a script element with an id of 'mstag_tops' to construct a URL. So you'd have to add that id to your s2 script.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is append the `iframe` from the `noscript` to your `body` tag on `click`.
I did it using jquery:

```
$('<iframe src="//flex.msn.com/mstag/tag/9cad6bfb-f783-447e-810c-0f9f1a0ae968/analytics.html?dedup=1&domainId=[12345]&type=1&actionid=[12345]" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden;display:none">').appendTo("body");
```